# python interval training analysis, counting rows based on heart rate and power

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, count

currently I am working on a dataset of an athletes running interval training. based on power values I want to automatically count the number of interval sessions in a training. so if power is above 200 watts I want to count the number of seconds of that high intensity period.

code below displays an example, numbers are not realistic

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:04'), 140, 120],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:05'), 160, 155],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:06'), 230, 156],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:07'), 230, 155],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:08'), 230, 160],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:09'), 140, 130],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:10'), 140, 131],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:11'), 230, 170]],
    columns=['timestamp', 'power', 'heart rate'])
```

so in the end I want to know how many seconds an athlete has been in the high power zone above 200 watts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can compute the `diff` between successive timestamps, then filter using boolean indexing and `sum`:

```
(-df['timestamp'].diff(-1))[df['power'].gt(200)].sum()
```

output:

```
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:03')
```

*NB. this is ignoring the last row as we don't know how long the last interval lasts.  If you want to consider that the interval is the same as the previous one:*

```
(-df['timestamp'].diff(-1).ffill())[df['power'].gt(200)].sum()
```

output:

```
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:04')
```

##### per stretch of continuous values above 200:

```
m = df['power'].gt(200)

(-df['timestamp'].diff(-1))[m].groupby((~m).cumsum()).sum()
```

output:

```
power
2   0 days 00:00:03
4   0 days 00:00:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: perfect this works but it sums up all the intervals. I would like to know the time per interval, so a training consists of 8 blocks and I  want to know the start time and length of each of these intervals

Comment: Then simply don't `sum`

Comment: but that will simply give a long list, I want a sum but per interval block and not for a whole training. resulting in a dataframe telling interval block 1 was 120 seconds started at this time ended at this time.

Comment: @pepijn see update if I understood correctly

Comment: one last question, what would be the easiest way to add mean, min, max columns for heart rate for each interval block?

Comment: use `agg` in place of `sum`: `agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])`

Comment: yes I know the  age function, but what is the best place to add the heart rate column in the code, as I  got the error that the data is in a series instead of a dataframe?

Comment: sorry, I don't follow you here

Comment: so, currently we have the power column and the timestamp column, where should I add the heart rate column if we want to calculate the mean heart rate during an interval block

Comment: So, in other words how can I add more columns to the groupby function, the most easy way?